# scale transition ruins inner shadow

Tags: javafx, scaletransform

the inner shadow disappears during the transition it looks like the inner shadow is also scaled.

```
public void showTowerRange(int x0, int y0, double range) {
    Circle circle = new Circle(
            x0 * MAP_CELLS_WIDTH + MAP_CELLS_WIDTH / 2,
            y0 * MAP_CELLS_HEIGHT + MAP_CELLS_HEIGHT / 2,
            1,
            Color.RED
    );
    circle.setOpacity(0.5);
    gameRoot.getChildren().add(circle);

    ScaleTransition scl = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(SHOW_RANGE_EFFECT_DURATION),circle);
    scl.setByX(range * MAP_CELLS_WIDTH);
    scl.setByY(range * MAP_CELLS_HEIGHT);

    FadeTransition fd = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(SHOW_RANGE_EFFECT_DURATION),circle);
    fd.setByValue(-.3);

    circle.setEffect(new InnerShadow(BlurType.GAUSSIAN, Color.GREEN, 4, 1, 0, 0));
    circle.setEffect(new DropShadow(BlurType.GAUSSIAN, Color.WHITE, 2, 0, 0, 0));
    ParallelTransition prl = new ParallelTransition(scl,fd);
    prl.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have good news and bad news for you. The good one - scale transition does not ruin inner shadow. The bad one - it is you ruining inner shadow:)
The point is, `setEffect()` method does not add another effect, it just set effect property of the Node, replacing previous value. What you need to do is to chain you effects (see example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/visual_effects/chain.htm)). So instead of this:

```
circle.setEffect(new InnerShadow(BlurType.GAUSSIAN, Color.GREEN, 4, 1, 0, 0));
circle.setEffect(new DropShadow(BlurType.GAUSSIAN, Color.WHITE, 2, 0, 0, 0));
```

You must do this:

```
InnerShadow is = new InnerShadow(BlurType.GAUSSIAN, Color.GREEN, 4, 1, 0, 0);
DropShadow ds = new DropShadow(BlurType.GAUSSIAN, Color.WHITE, 2, 0, 0, 0);
ds.setInput(is);
circle.setEffect(ds);
```